# Python, get value just one if the value is same

Tags: python, list, loops

i was try to find similiar question like i want to ask right now. But, the answer not really helping me. I was try to get value, but just one value if the value is same. here my code :

first, i have condition like this

```
ids_data = []
arr_rest_ids = [('8380128579', 309), ('8380128579', 311), ('8380128579', 310), ('8380222579', 313)]

if arr_rest_ids:
    for i in arr_rest_ids:
        ids_data.append(i)
```

I have condition string and integer, the condition tell that integer have a value. I was try to create a condition if the value is same than get the value just one.

I want the result be like this :

```
ids_data = [309, 313]
arr_rest_ids = [('8380128579', 309), ('8380128579', 311), ('8380128579', 310), ('8380222579', 313)]

if arr_rest_ids:
    for i in arr_rest_ids:
        ids_data.append(i)
```

the ids_data variable show the id just a different value.

Comment: Is order important? If not, just convert to a `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to maintain a set of the values you have seen:

```
arr_rest_ids = [('8380128579', 309), ('8380128579', 311), ('8380128579', 310), ('8380222579', 313)]
ids_data = []
seen = set()

# no check needed here. If arr_rest_ids is empty, the loop won't start
for x, y in arr_rest_ids:
    if x not in seen:
        ids_data.append(y)
        seen.add(x)
```

In Python3, you can also use this hack to achieve the same in fewer lines:

```
seen = set()
ids_data = [seen.add(x) or y for x, y in arr_rest_ids if x not in seen]
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's work for me. But, can you explain to me why there is no need to check every single value ? On my logic that i have to check every single value to know the value is same or not. @schwobaseggl

Comment: @Scarlettstone You **do** check every single value with `x in seen`, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: No, I was try to check using ```for i in arr_rest_ids for j in i```

Comment: Aw do you want to also avoid duplicate  ids (309, etc.) in your resulting ids?

Comment: Your inner loop will loop through the elements of the inner tuples, but those do not not require the same treatment. The first is used for the duplicate check, the second is added to the result list.  You'd loop through them only if you wanted to do the same thing with them.

Comment: That's clearly enough for me, thank you so much @schwobaseggl